# How I can copy folder in google drive api?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

The documentation describes how to copy one file (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy), but nothing is said about the folder. This script, when copying a folder, gives an error 403:

```
window.gapi.client.drive.files
          .create({
            resource: {
              name: this.currentFile.newTitle,
              mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
            },
            fields: 'id, name, mimeType, createdTime'
          }).then(res => {
            window.gapi.client.drive.files.list({
              q: `'${this.currentFile.id}' in parents and trashed = false`,
              fields: 'files(id, name, createdTime, mimeType)'
            }).then(res => {
              console.log(res)
              res.result.files.forEach(file => {
                window.gapi.client.drive.files
                  .copy({
                    fileId: file.id,
                    fields: 'id, name, mimeType, createdTime'
                  }).then(res => console.log(res))
              })
            })
          })
```

I tried other solutions that I found on the Internet, but they also did not work. Could you please attach some sample code that works for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

files.copy does just that copies a single file

[image]

If you check the very top of the documentation page that you linked you will notice it states it does not work on folders.

To copy a folder you should first do a file.create and create a folder the do a file.list to loop though all of the files in the folder then do a file.copy on each of the files.

There is no bulk copy everything in a folder method. Your going to have to do this one by one.

Comment: Thanks! But could you tell me how to make a loop with copying correctly in this case? I have updated the description where I tried to do it myself. But if there are other folders inside the folder that I copy, then it does not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've published a pypi package to copy a google drive folder. It recursively copies files down the file directory from a folder you specified

https://pypi.org/project/googledrive-cloner/